# how to place title of the image on bottom of the image

Tags: css, reactjs, fancybox, react-props

am fetching article from CMS, it contains images, therefore am making slideshow when photo is clicked using fancyapps-ui/fancybox in React.js. images also contain title, so when photo is hovered, I can see description like this
[image]

my mission: I when clicked, image is getting zoomed, and I want that same description to be on bottom of the image, in the red area
[image]

I was searching for it, I tried using title and caption but nothing worked, I know that it has a props or something like that but I could not find it. any tips?

Comment: Did you read the docs? https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/getting-started/#create-elements

Comment: I could not find the right docs, thanks man, appreaciate it!